# Java FX launch multiple files from one interface

Tags: javafx

How would I go about creating an interface that allowed me to launch three different Java files (for this case games) and would let the user pick between them?

The games are already done and each in a sperate file, but I need to combine them so they can be played upon selection from the user.

Really confused just trying to read something that could get me started or on the right track to combine them.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], or describe in greater details. Based on your explanation, we are not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: his goal was to create an `interface` that allows him to launch a class. it had minimal code. his question resemble the complete requirement. i was able to generate an answer. my answer shows it can be verifiable. i'm not sure why the negative downvote nor am i sure why the comment above. please elaborate.

Comment: he didn't specify what type of interface, so i did my best to attempt an answer. he did ask "*just trying to read something that could get me started or on the right track*", so i make an attempt to answer him. perhaps you can better the attempt then. all contribution is welcomed :)

Answer (score -3):

```
 interface GameSelectionListener {
  NameOfTheClassGame1 gameOneListener();
  NameOfTheClassGame2 gameTwoListener();
  NameOfTheClassGame3 gameThreeListener();
 } //end of interface

 public class GameLoader implements GameSelectionListener {

 public GameLoader(){
  ... some user io to select game ...
  switch(user selection for your game){
  case 1: this.gameOneListener();
  case 2: this.gameTwoListener();
  case 3: this.gameThreeListener();
  } //end of switch
 } //end of constructor

 @OverrideNameOfTheClassGame1 gameOneListener(){
  new GameOne();
 }
 @OverrideNameOfTheClassGame2 gameTwoListener(){
  new GameTwo();
 } 
 @OverrideNameOfTheClassGame3 gameThreeListener(){
  new GameThree();
 }
} //end of class
```